# How do I pass commands to an external command, from bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, programming

I would like know if it is possible to enter in an external program and give commands from a bash script.

As an example, lets imagine the external program is ipython and I want to give the commands

```
print 'hello world' 
exit
```

If I try to create a sh script like:

`echo 'ipython | print 'hello world' | exit' > wtvr.sh`

then obviously it doesnt work...
Is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you still using Python2?

Comment: python2 is becoming obsolete soon.

Comment: ipython is interactive python. Not a good choice for non interactive stuff. Instead use python.

Comment: sorry, the 2 was a mistake, just corrected. yes, indeed im using python2 and unfortunately it has its days counted :/

Comment: and i dont want to do this in python, it was just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
printf 'print("hello world")\n exit\n' | ipython
```

And you don't even need `exit` as `ipython` automatically exits after reading commands from standard input so as well you could do:

```
echo 'print("hello world")' | ipython
```

Comment: perfect thanks :)

Comment: would you tell me how it would go to give 2 command lines to the external program instead of 1? So, for instance, imagine I want to print hello and world separated but in the same ipython session. Something like:

echo 'print("hello"), print("world")' | ipython

Comment: `printf 'print("hello")\n print("world")\n' | ipython`, just like in my first example.